# How to read the text and color of the text from an Image using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have to read the text but I need the `RGB` Value of the text. How can I get it?
I'm reading the text using the below code-segment. 
Can anyone help me out?

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string
print(image_to_string(Image.open('images.png')))
```

Comment: If the color is not varying then it is simple otherwise if shades are similar averaging can be used. Can you please show the image. @sheetal